# DAX - Summarize on different granularity level

Tags: dax

I have the following "fact" table in Excel 2013:

```
+----------+-------+-----------+---------------+----------------+
| Employee | Month | Branch_Id | Branch Target | Employee sales |
+----------+-------+-----------+---------------+----------------+
| John     |     1 | A         |           100 |             20 |
| John     |     2 | A         |           100 |             10 |
| Dave     |     1 | B         |            80 |             30 |
| Dave     |     2 | B         |            80 |              5 |
| Paul     |     1 | A         |           100 |             20 |
| Paul     |     2 | A         |           100 |             60 |
+----------+-------+-----------+---------------+----------------+
```

The column "Branch Target" is delivered by a Join clause from table "Targets":

```
+--------+--------+
| Branch | Target |
+--------+--------+
| A      |    100 |
| B      |     80 |
+--------+--------+
```

Now, I wish to have a dynamic  calculation of two fields: "Branch Target" and "Employee Sales", so the final output will be as follow:

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| Branch | Target | Sales |
+--------+--------+-------+
| A      |    100 |   110 |
| B      |     80 |    35 |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

I'm struggling with the Target coulmn since a SUM function will summrize according to all the rows it apears in the Fact table and - i.e. - for branch A it will yeild 400.

I thought of using an average (400/4 = 100) for adjusting it, however it is not a dynamic solution and doesn't hold when I remove the Branch "grouping" from the output pivot.

Appreciate your help.

Asaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the target from the big fact table (let's call that the Sales table). Add the targets table to Power Pivot. Add a new table with one row per Branch and call it branch. Branch in the Sales fact table should foreign key to the new Branch table. Branch in the targets table should foreign key to the new Branch table. Hide (right click and Hide from Client tools) the branch column in the Fact table and the targets table. Create a simple sum measure for your Branch target:

```
Branch Target := SUM('Targets'[Target])
```

That's it. Basically load your tables at their native grain into Power Pivot and it will do the rest.

The other best practice you will notice in the above is that if you have two tables with measures you need to have a separate dimension table.